# How does the elemental DoT of two weapons of the same element stack?

Tags: borderlands-2

I already understand how overtime dmg/sec works for elemental weapons (Shock/Corrosive/Fire), but if I decide to switch between two weapons of the *same* element, such as the Heartbreaker (81.6 dmg/sec) and the Gospel (180.4 dmg/sec), both fire, and shot the *same* enemy, would the damage stack? Replace the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elemental damage over time from the *same* gun stacks, actually. There's no difference for switching guns, using abilities with different elements, etc.

Each stack of DOT exists completely on it's own and will die on it's own, and more will be added if an elemental hit procs regardless of other sticks.. Best I can tell, there's no maximum number of DOT stacks currently active, either.

Comment: Actually I'm pretty sure the only weapon that will stack the element effect on its own is the hellfire, which is the only reason it is any good. If all weapons did this there would be no need for that legendary.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to demonstrate this is simply to use three weapons with the three DoT elements on the same target. You will see the DoT numbers cascade in the three different colours. This means each shot that causes the effect causes DoT regardless of the source.